# vertical-align middle not working on table-cell

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Please Check http://jsfiddle.net/4Ly4B/ I've `vertical-align: middle` on a `table-cell` which is not coming to the middle

Answer (score 2):

An element with `display:table-cell` ignores `min-width` and `min-height`. You have to use `height` and `width` instead.
Also, if you want to position the element using `position:absolute`, you wrap the element in a container, and assign `position:absolute` to this container.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ly4B/3/

Comment: Do you mean assign `position: relative;` to the container?

Answer (score 0):

vertical-align: middle; it's basicall used for table-cell.in your example position is absolute
this way u can do this

```
.message{
background-color: gray;
position: absolute;
min-width: 200px;
display: table-cell;
padding:60px 0px 60px 0px;
text-align: center;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The property **vertical-align** doesn't work with **min-height**. Remove **min-height** and add **padding** instead of it.

```
.message{
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    min-width: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```